# PySpark: java.io.EOFException When Reading Data from HDFS - How to Fix?

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, py4j

I'm facing an issue when trying to read data from the Hadoop Distributed File System (HDFS) using PySpark. I'm using Py4J version 0.10.9.7 and Java 8 with Spark 3.5.0. However, I keep getting the following error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.showString.
: java.io.EOFException: End of File Exception between local host is: "xxxx/xx.xxx.xx.xxx"; destination host is: "xxx":xxxx; : java.io.EOFException; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EOFException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)      
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:913)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:862)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1616)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1558)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:242)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine2$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine2.java:129)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy42.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:965)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:422)   
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:165)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:157)    
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95) 
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:359)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy43.getFileInfo(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.getFileInfo(DFSClient.java:1739)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1753)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$29.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1750)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1765)       
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.getFileStatus(Globber.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.doGlob(Globber.java:349)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Globber.glob(Globber.java:202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.globStatus(FileSystem.java:2142)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:276)       
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:244)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:332)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:49)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:291)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:501)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4344)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4334)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)        
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)        
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4332)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3326)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3549)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$IpcStreams.readResponse(Client.java:1922)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.receiveRpcResponse(Client.java:1238)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.run(Client.java:1134)
```

I have tried several troubleshooting steps such as checking the availability of the data source, inspecting Spark configurations, and ensuring network connectivity. However, the issue remains unresolved.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any suggestions for handling this EOFException error? I appreciate any help and insights you can provide.

this is mycode want to execute :

```
df = spark.sql("select * from contact.phone limit 5")
df.show()
```